# Detect whether all database-held resources are present in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, resources

I currently hold my resources in a database instead of resx files. I would like to be able to test whether all keys used in the application are held in the database to avoid runtime errors.

I have a custom `ResourceProviderFactory` to accomplish retrieving the resources.

Resources could be in aspx view pages - `GetLocalResourceObject("ResourceKey")` or `GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceClass", "ResourceKey")`.

They could be in a controller - `HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("ResourceClass", "ResourceKey")`.

I also call the resources from the core assemblies of my application without using the ASP.NET resource factory (using a singleton instead) - `CoreResources.Current.GetResource("ResourceClass", "ResourceKey")`

What would be the best way for me to ensure that all resources are in the database without having to waiting for a runtime exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only approach I can think of is writing an app that scans your source code files and extracts all the resource keys you are using. You can then check the existence of each key in your database.
Unfortunately it is not so trivial... I don't think there is an easier way.

I would however change your ResourceProviderFactory to not throw an exception in case of a missing key. Just return some text like "Resource missing: 'xxx'" and log it so that it can be added.

Comment: Yeah I've considered doing that and I think it'll probably mitigate some of the risks. I'll write a parser and see how effective it is.